# How would it be possible to engineer cows to have more offspring?

Tags: genetics, synthetic-biology, gene-synthesis

Cows usually only give birth to one calf per year and only several in their lifetime. What would we have to genetically alter so they can have more offspring, more frequently. I read that their is a record for most births from one cow at once: 16. How could we possibly genetically engineer a cow to make this them give birth more frequently?

Comment: High potential of being unanswerable due the large number of physiological aspects likely to be involved and our lack of understanding of them.

Answer (score 3):

With a couple of notable exceptions, the vast majority of agricultural "genetic engineering" is by selective breeding; the answer would typically be "continually mate cattle from lineages with high fecundity together". Little knowledge of biology beyond that is necessary.

However, you could also look for particular alleles involved in increased fecundity; here's a paper talking about one example:

*Kamalludin, M. H., Garcia-Guerra, A., Wiltbank, M. C., & Kirkpatrick, B. W. (2018). Trio, a novel high fecundity allele: I. Transcriptome analysis of granulosa cells from carriers and noncarriers of a major gene for bovine ovulation rate. Biology of Reproduction, 98(3), 323-334.*

If you wanted to raise a herd that had a high rate of this gene, again, you could use selective breeding alongside genotyping to propagate that particular allele.

It's a bit more complicated than just making lots of bovines, though; if you're doing this for agriculture, it's going to be quite important that the offspring have healthy development so they can be used for milk or meat. I'm not an expert in the field so I may be mistaken, but it doesn't seem like fecundity is a crucial limiting factor for cattle.